# What does this mean? I see this all the time in comments, in flash actionscript

Tags: flash, comments

What does this mean?

```
/**
 * ...
 * @author ...
 */
```

and now do i use it?

thanks! (tried google-ing first, but wildcards are throwing it off)

Answer (score 8):

They are [Javadocs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comments, a format to write code comments that started with Java, and is some other languages picked the syntax.

There are parsers available that will read your code files and generate HTML output from them, to easily document an API.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your quick and accurate answer!

Comment: Actually they are called asdoc comments in actionscript. ASDoc, like javadoc, comes free with the flex framework.